# Can not access MongoDB data after upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I've installed mongodb-community, launched it as a service.

In the process I've overriten symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` and now they point to `../Cellar/mongodb-community/4.2.0/bin`.

Before this symlinks pointed to `../Cellar/mongodb/4.0.3/bin`, and this folder is still there.

How can I use all mongodb data (databases, users, etc) from the previous mongo version?

I currently can connect to localhost via Robo3T but fail to get db list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update mongodb from 4 or lower versions to 4.2 is to

```
a) create dump of all data;
b) uninstall completely current mongodb;
c) install mongodb 4.2 (community edition);
d) delete all mongodata in order to restore them from dump later;
e) restore data from dump;
g) run mongo service;
```